# Count number of LineStrings in a MultiLineString MySQL

Tags: mysql, geospatial

Is there a sql way to count the number of linestrings in a multilinestring field in MySQL? ST_Numpoints(multilinestring_field) returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is using ST_NumGeometries - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-geometrycollection-property-functions.html#function_st-numgeometries